# Different colors in object.function is VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image: VS Code example for differenct colors]

I can't find how I could have different colors in object.function. datetime.now for example.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highlighting for Python code in VS Code is provided by [MagicPython](https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython). Colouring will be based on how they classify something and your colour scheme (i.e. some themes don't utilize different colours for everything that has been uniquely identified).